# Separate dll for class library

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class library with multiple cs files, when I build it, it generates a dll file which I reference in my project. Its okay when I change only one cs file, suppose I have changes in multiple file but wish to get only that particular change in the dll rather than those unnecessary cs files.

As an option

1. we can create separate class library and hence separate dll for every classes, but that it the last option I guess
2. use a preprocessor directives like

   ```
   #define VC7
   //...
   #if debug
       Console.Writeline("Debug build");
   #elif VC7
       Console.Writeline("Visual Studio 7");
   #endif
   ```

but we need to have this thing in designer too

So what is the best solution??

Comment: A "separate DLL for every class"? Surely that is *not* a winning strategy. (I'm not sure what the problem is, but perhaps use a Version Control System?)

Comment: It's called Source Code revision control and branching...

Comment: Can you clarify this statement "suppose I have changes in multiple file but wish to get only that particular change in the dll rather than those unnecessary cs files."?

Comment: @nous: suppose I have worked in multiple cs files but are incomplete, so I need to have only the one that are complete on the dll so that it doesnt get me an error. And any help or links would be appreciated

Comment: I think you are looking for a mechanism to automatically take code that compiles and merge it into a dll with code that used to compile.  This would be a no. Is there something you are not describing about your problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat I was using SVN then and my problem was in committing those different cs file with some business logic errors and it would have been clearer if I had mention it earlier :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to commit the whole class library rather than only dll from the project's bin.

My Fault was that I was committing only dll so whenever I committed dlls I committed both approved and unapproved changes from .cs so those who updated from that change were getting errors whereas now everyone update the class library and rebuilds it ignoring even faulty cs file there and use it.

It was kind of silly :-)

Answer (score 1):

TFS (or other version control system) can do this.  Set up TFS as a build server and only check in files that are ready to be compiled.  There are ***MANY*** ways to set this up.  Do the research.

Start by reading up on `continuous build` and/or `continuous integration`, then read up on how various version control systems implement that.

Comment: sorry for delayed response, but that time I was using SVN for versioning and TFS was just other option